# Custom photo folder showing up in Gallery

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm working on an app that uses the camera and saves the pictures to DCIM/MyAppFolder. My first question is should I be saving it to DCIM or Pictures? If it even matters. My second question is I noticed it takes a while for the folder/pictures to show up in the native gallery app. After testing this with other apps (Instagram, Snapseed, ect) those photos show up immediately. Is there a piece of code I'm missing to accomplish this? My code is as followed:

```
public void takePhoto() {
    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());

    //folder stuff
    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "MyAppFolder");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    //String filePath = "/MyImages/QR_" + timeStamp + ".png" ;
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);

    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to update the gallery app. simply after you click save just put this simple code after saving.

```
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                Uri.parse("file://"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

this code will tell the gallery app that something has been added so please rescan for media now :D.

Comment: Do I have to change `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)`?